# Ember.js Bindings Tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

According to the Ember [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/) this snippet should set the `houseHoldIncome` property of the `App.wife` instance.

```
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

App.husband.get('householdIncome'); // 80000

// Someone gets raise.
App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);
console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome')); // 90000
```

`console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome'))` still outputs 80000. Is this due bindings aren't updated immediatly or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
It appears that bindings aren't updated immediatly.

```
App.wife.addObserver('householdIncome', function() {
    console.log('Wife income changed: '+App.wife.get('householdIncome'));
});
```

This will output the updated income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior because ember queue some changes using a lib called [backburner](https://github.com/ebryn/backburner.js). The advantage of this is that several changes in a model atribute, for example in a foreach, will just render one time. So you don't need to care about performance, in observers and dom updating.

If you use `Ember.run.sync()` you can force the binding to flush so you will see the changes being propagated:

```
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

App.husband.get('householdIncome'); // 80000

// Someone gets raise.
App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);
Ember.run.sync();
console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome')); // 90000
```

In that fiddle you will see the wife `householdIncome` property being updated http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/uCr3C/